# Which is suitable to use for this sentence

Tags: phrasal-verbs

which is correct?

Part of me is grateful thay he (didn't / doesn't) has an twitter account.

or should i write this

Part of me is grateful for his non-existence of twitter account.

thank for your help :)

Comment: None of them are correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't have" and "didn't have" are both fine: the difference is whether you are thinking about his continuing to have one or not. If he didn't have one at the relevant time in the past, but may have one now, you want "didn't have"; If he has never had one, you could use either.

"Doesn't has" and "didn't has" are not grammatical: the auxiliary "do" is **always always always** followed by the base form of the verb.

"The non-existence of his twitter account" is possible, but belongs in a philosphy paper, not in ordinary speech. "His non-existence of twitter account" is grammatical but makes no sense.

**Edited** to turn the logic round: HT SamBC.

Comment: Isn't it more that if he currently has no account, it's "doesn't have", but if he may or may not currently have one, but at some point in the past he had none, that's "didn't have"?

Comment: @SamBC: you're right. I was forgetting the negative. I'll edit.